# ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away - Despite changes to Configuration File

Tags: mysql

I am using XAMPP with the following configuration on Windows 10

```
PHP version: 7.4.12
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.12
Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/7.4.12
Server version: 10.4.16-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)
```

I am trying to import a SQL database which has 500,000+ rows in it. Its actual size is 90 MB post converting it into UTF-8. In its original endcoding it was 179 MB but was throwing up errors when I tried to import it.

Now during trying to import it, I am constantly getting this infamous error:-

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
```

I have searched on other threads and the fixes suggested so far haven't helped. There is no my.cnf file in XAMPP version so I have made changes to my.ini file under the [mysql] tag which looks like this below at the moment

```
[mysql]
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE
connect_timeout = 1000000
net_write_timeout = 1000000
wait_timeout = 1000000
max_allowed_packet = 512M
interactive_timeout = 1000000
net_buffer_length = 64M
net_read_timeout = 1000000
set GLOBAL delayed_insert_timeout=100000

[mysqld]
port=3306
socket="E:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir="E:/xampp/mysql"
tmpdir="E:/xampp/tmp"
datadir="E:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file="mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer=16M
sort_buffer_size=512K
net_buffer_length=64M
read_buffer_size=256K
read_rnd_buffer_size=512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M
log_error="mysql_error.log"
max_allowed_packet = 512M
net_read_timeout = 1000000
```

Yet, I am still getting the error. I am using the following command in DOS to import the file

```
mysql -u root -p data_batch_avi < data_ina_utf8.sql --verbose --force --wait --reconnect
```

**Also, I am trying to export a database in SQL from the same system which has 43 million rows in it and is occupying 10.5GB.** Please suggest ways to do so and if possible something that splits it in part while exporting as if and when I will try to import it I will again face issues.

Comment: All options should come before the "< data_ina_utf8.sql". Would it be possible to split the input in smaller chunks?

Comment: Did you restart the server after modifying these settings ?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server.

Comment: How can I split the file into smaller chunks. It is a SQL file.

Comment: Have increased max packet size limit to 512M and trying again. Doubt it will work but in the meantime looking for suggestions here.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.